# Copying data from text into new columns in R

Tags: r, extract, social-networking

I have compiled a dataset of tweets using the Twitter API.

The dataset basically looks as follows:

```
Data <- data.frame(
  X = c(1,2),
  text = c("Hello @User1 #hashtag1, hello @User2 and @User3, #hashtag2", "Hello @User2 #hashtag3, hello @User1 and @User3, #hashtag4"),
  screenname = c("author1", "author2")
)
```

Now I want to create a `data.frame` for social network analysis. I want to show how each of the screennames (in the case of this example "author1" etc.) is linked to users ("@User1" etc.) and hashtags ("#hashtag1", etc.).

To so, I need to extract/copy users and hashtags from the "text" column and write them in new columns. The `data.frame`should look like this:

```
Data <- data.frame(
  X = c(1,2),
  text = c("Hello @User1 #hashtag1, hello @User2 and @User3, #hashtag2", "Hello @User2 #hashtag3, hello @User1 and @User3, #hashtag4"),
  screenname = c("author1", "author2"),
  U1 = c("@User1", "@User2"),
  U2 = c("@User2", "@User1"),
  U3 = c("@User3", "@User3"),
  U4 = c("",""),
  U5 = c("",""),
  H1 = c("#hashtag1", "#hashtag3"),
  H2 = c("#hashtag2", "#hashtag4"),
  H3 = c("",""),
  H4 = c("",""),
  H5 = c("","")
)
```

How can I extract/copy this information from the "text" column and write it into new columns?

Comment: What do you have empty `U4` and `U5` columns for?

Comment: I do not know how many users one author mentions in his/her tweet. so I inserted 5 columns for possible users mentioned in a tweet (knowing, that it can be more).

Comment: Are you running this procedure several times or you just get this `Data` and you want to convert to `Data2` once? You can just set the amount of columns by the maximum size of Users or hashtags

Comment: I have a big dataset with ten-thousands of observations.

Comment: Ok, try my solution using `stringi` package. I've tested it on different string lengths and it works fine. It is also 99% vectorized so should work fine on a big data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my simple attempt using `stringi` package. This method will create the amount of columns as the longest string in users and hastags, so this will work for *any* number of users or hashtags mentioned. This is also will be very efficient because this solution is mostly vectorized.

```
library(stringi)
Users <- stri_extract_all(Data$text, regex = "@[A-Za-z0-9]+")
Data[paste0("U", seq_len(max(sapply(Users, length))))] <- stri_list2matrix(Users, byrow = TRUE)
Hash <- stri_extract_all(Data$text, regex = "#[A-Za-z0-9]+")
Data[paste0("H", seq_len(max(sapply(Hash, length))))] <- stri_list2matrix(Hash, byrow = TRUE)
Data
#   X                                                       text screenname     U1     U2     U3        H1        H2
# 1 1 Hello @User1 #hashtag1, hello @User2 and @User3, #hashtag2    author1 @User1 @User2 @User3 #hashtag1 #hashtag2
# 2 2 Hello @User2 #hashtag3, hello @User1 and @User3, #hashtag4    author2 @User2 @User1 @User3 #hashtag3 #hashtag4
```

Comment: wow, that works! Just one thing: the users and hashtags are not filled in sequence. so sometimes a hashtag finds itself in the column H15, although there are only 5 hashtags. Do know why?

Comment: I couldn't tell without a reproducible example.

Comment: I am not allowed to make the dataset public, but can I mail it to you?

Comment: You can just provide an example a single tweet that it happens and encrypt the names so the error will still occur but you want publish the actual names

Comment: it is almost impossible to create an example of 4 single tweets. there is so much information in this dataset. i am not able to extract it using dput

Comment: I think I found the error - with your script, the Users are not copied in sequence within a row, but within a column. In the example above, the output of users in the first row should be user1, user2, user3 instead of user1, user3, user1. But how can I change that?

Comment: Sorry, I've made a small mistake. I've edited the code, try again.

Comment: one last question: how must the code look like, if I want to have all the users in one column (called "target"), and separated by a comma?

Comment: You'll have to show me your desired output with the provided `Data`.

Comment: I want to import the csv file into Gephi. According to Gephi, I need the following file format: http://gephi.github.io/users/supported-graph-formats/csv-format/

Comment: It starts to get confusing, sorry. Should I edit my question and describe the whole Problem? I am really sorry for the mess of confusing questions!

Comment: I think you should accept this solution because it answered your original question correctly. And then ask a new question maybe.

Comment: You are right. Thank You. Maybe You can also answer the other question.

Comment: You can post a link in comments and I'll take a look later today (if it still won't be answered).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28302705/exporting-twitter-data-to-gephi-using-r